# Switching to child theme breaks a few things

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

A site I just took over for uses a 3rd party theme, with some modifications made by a previous developer. The site owner wanted the theme upgraded, so I installed the updated theme. The previous modifications didn't show as expected, but other than that the site looked good. My plan was to make a child theme and incorporate the changes into that. The theme actually comes with a child theme option, so I installed that, but once I activated it, a bunch of things stopped working. The entire header was messed up, things were missing etc. I haven't even started trying to make changes yet. I was under the impression that the empty (or virtually empty) child theme wouldn't change anything until I started making modifications. Especially if it came with the theme.

Is this sort of thing normal? Is there a way to make the child theme work exactly like the parent theme?

Comment: How did you created you chip theme ? did you follow that : https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/ ?

Comment: @Pof When downloading the updated theme, it came with an empty child theme.  I compared it to the instructions on creating a new theme and it seemed to match.